# Constraint exception in UIPageViewController only when style is set to 'Scroll'

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I am using a UIPageView to allow users to scroll through a collection of images, and am getting a constraint error (no common ancestor) when the `UIPageViewController` is set to the `Scroll` transition style, but not when it is set to `Page Curl`.

So far I've tried changing the anchors of the constraints throwing the errors (I've identified exactly which ones are the culprit) to different things (tried `Safe Area` and `Superview`), but nothing has made a difference. I'm relatively new to Swift, and don't know much about how `UIPageViewController`'s work, so there's a good chance I'm just calling things in the wrong order and not realizing it. I am a little confused though why the error is *only* happening with the `Scroll` transition style and not the `Page Curl`, since it seems to me like they should work similarly... Also confused about why the constraint anchors aren't in the same view hierarchy when it's anchored to its own superview?

Here's the `UIPageViewController` delegate:

```swift
class ImageDetailPageViewController: UIPageViewController {

    // MARK: Properties

    var images: [UIImage]!
    var index: Int!

    var navbarHeight: CGFloat!

    fileprivate lazy var pages: [UIViewController] = {
        return getPages()
    }()

    // MARK: Methods

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.dataSource = self
        self.delegate = self

        self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        setViewControllers([pages[index]], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }

    // MARK: Methods

    fileprivate func getPages() -> [ImageView] {
        var pages = [ImageView]()

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "ImageDetail", bundle: nil)

        for image in images {
            let imageDetail = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ImageDetail") as! ImageView
            imageDetail.image = image

            pages.append(imageDetail)
        }

        return pages
    }
}

// MARK: Extensions

extension ImageDetailPageViewController: UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let viewControllerIndex = pages.firstIndex(of: viewController) else {
            return nil
        }

        let previousIndex = viewControllerIndex - 1

        guard previousIndex >= 0 else {
            return pages.last
        }

        guard pages.count > previousIndex else {
            return nil
        }

        return pages[previousIndex]
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {       
        guard let viewControllerIndex = pages.firstIndex(of: viewController) else {
            return nil
        }

        let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex + 1

        guard nextIndex < pages.count else {
            return pages.first
        }

        guard pages.count > nextIndex else {
            return nil
        }

        return pages[nextIndex]
    }

    func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return pages.count
    }

    func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return index
    }
}

extension ImageDetailPageViewController: UIPageViewControllerDelegate { }
```

The view controller in the page view (`ImageDetail`) is quite simple. It consists of a `UIScrollView` anchored to the `Safe Area`, with a `UIImageView` anchored to the `UIScrollView`.

The app crashes as soon as I try to scroll to the next page in the page view, throwing the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x600001b72400 "UIImageView:0x7ff44c56caf0.top"> and <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x600001b77e40 "UIScrollView:0x7ff44d164800.top"> because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'
```

When set to `Page Curl`, it works perfectly. The view controller also renders perfectly fine when loaded on its own, outside the page view.

**EDIT:**
Here's the code for the `ImageDetail` view:

```swift
class ImageView: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    // MARK: Properties

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var zoomGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer!

    // imageView contraints
    @IBOutlet var imageViewBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet var imageViewLeadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet var imageViewTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet var imageViewTrailingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    var image: UIImage!

    // MARK: Overrides

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // set the image
        if let image = image {
            imageView.image = image
        } else {
            // log error
            os_log("Error. Image Detail opened without an image loaded.", log: OSLog.default, type: .error)

            // dismiss view
            self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
        }

        // assume scrollView delegate
        scrollView.delegate = self
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 2

        // set imageView snapshot mode
        imageView.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true)
    }

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

        updateMinZoomScaleForSize(view.compatibleSafeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame.size)
        updateConstraintsForSize(view.compatibleSafeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame.size)
        scrollView.setZoomScale(scrollView.minimumZoomScale, animated: false)
    }

    // MARK: Methods

    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return imageView
    }

    func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        updateConstraintsForSize(view.compatibleSafeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame.size)
    }

    fileprivate func updateConstraintsForSize(_ size: CGSize) {
        let yOffset = max(0, (view.compatibleSafeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame.height - imageView.frame.height) / 2)
        imageViewTopConstraint.constant = yOffset
        imageViewBottomConstraint.constant = yOffset

        let xOffset = max(0, (view.compatibleSafeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame.width - imageView.frame.width) / 2)
        imageViewLeadingConstraint.constant = xOffset
        imageViewTrailingConstraint.constant = xOffset

        // activate constraints
        imageViewTopConstraint.isActive = true
        imageViewBottomConstraint.isActive = true
        imageViewLeadingConstraint.isActive = true
        imageViewTrailingConstraint.isActive = true

        view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    fileprivate func updateMinZoomScaleForSize(_ size: CGSize) {
        let widthScale = view.compatibleSafeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame.width / imageView.bounds.width
        let heightScale = view.compatibleSafeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame.height / imageView.bounds.height
        let minScale = min(widthScale, heightScale)

        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = minScale
        scrollView.zoomScale = minScale
    }

    fileprivate func zoomRectForScale(_ scale: CGFloat, center: CGPoint) -> CGRect {
        // create and size view window
        var zoomRect = CGRect.zero
        zoomRect.size.height = imageView.frame.size.height
        zoomRect.size.width = imageView.frame.size.width

        // center on tapped point
        let newCenter = imageView.convert(center, from: view)
        zoomRect.origin.x = newCenter.x - (zoomRect.size.width / 2.0)
        zoomRect.origin.y = newCenter.y - (zoomRect.size.height / 2.0)

        // return rect
        return zoomRect
    }

    // MARK: Actions

    @IBAction func tapToZoom(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if scrollView.zoomScale == scrollView.minimumZoomScale {
            scrollView.zoom(to: zoomRectForScale(scrollView.maximumZoomScale, center: zoomGestureRecognizer.location(in: zoomGestureRecognizer.view)), animated: true)
        } else {
            scrollView.setZoomScale(scrollView.minimumZoomScale, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

And the corresponding storyboard:
[Storyboard screenshot](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1Yb0in6TKSmZEph6nxi1bGtS7ZMxTNMA1)

Comment: `self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` comment this line and it will work!

Comment: @SohilR.Memon commented that and got the exact same error :(

Comment: You need to show the screenshot of your storyboard with imageView and scrollView, or show us the code. Because that's where your Xcode points you to.

Comment: @Jai Please add or update constraints in `viewDidLoad` and see what happens? Because `viewWillLayoutSubviews` can be called multiple times based on your `UIView`'s.

Comment: @SohilR.Memon The constraints in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` allow for zooming and panning of the image, so they need to be updated where they are (I think?). No new constraints are being added, they're just updating based on how zoomed in the `ScrollView` is. **Edit:** just tried it, and as expected the image didn't appear at all (attempts to size itself before the view has dimensions, and then doesn't update when the view is zoomed/panned)

Comment: @Jai Can you pls send me a demo project to see?

Comment: @SohilR.Memon here's a demo project: https://github.com/jaismith/TestApp, sorry for the slow reply, thanks for helping out!

Comment: @Jai The problem is in this line `imageView.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true)` once you comment this it will start working! Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came to know that this line `imageView.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true)` explicitly tell to render the appearance of `UIImageView` and if it fails then the snapshot might not have visible content.

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve but commenting out that line will surely solve your problem. Do let me know if you need any help in rendering the UI of what you want or something else.

Read the official [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622531-snapshotview) for more details.

Comment: Hi again! Follow up question: when I comment out `imageView.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true)` the image renders improperly and the scrollView zooming breaks (zooms out infinitely). I've updated the demo project with the changes and would greatly appreciate any additional pointers you have.